# Using .gitignore to ignore files inside of git status

Tags: git, version-control

When I run `git status`, I have unrelated files that I do not want watched.

For example:

> M .gitignore
>   M as3-remote/.project
>   M perspective/swc/.project
>   M perspective/swf/.project
>   M scheduled-translator-framework/src/main/java/Importer.java
>   D scheduled-translator-framework/src/main/java/TranslatorTest.java
>   M ui-mecogis/swf/.project

I have already tried editing my .gitignore so that includes .projects
My .gitignore looks like:

> .classpath
>   .project
>   .settings
>   *.log
>   nbactions.xml
>   target
>   .DS_Store

I only want to track and watch changes inside the scheduled-translator-framework, and I only want to focus on .java files in that specific folder. I don't want anything else to show up under tracked or untracked that is unrelated. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that's what you need:

```
# in .gitignore
*
!scheduled-translator-framework/
!scheduled-translator-framework/*
```

and:

```
# in scheduled-translator-framework/.gitignore 
/*
!*/
!*.java
```

Using `.gitignore` in the root of the project we:

1. Ignore everything.
2. Unignore `scheduled-translator-framework/` directory.
3. Unignore **all** files inside `scheduled-translator-framework/` (we'll handle files in this directory later).

Using `.gitignore` in the `scheduled-translator-framework/` directory we:

1. Ignore everything in this subdirectory.
2. Unignore all subdirectories inside `scheduled-translator-framework/` (necessary for the next step to work).
3. Unignore all `*java` files in the current directory (that is `scheduled-translator-framework/`) and all subdirectories.

If, by accident, you have added to index or commited some of the files that you don't want to track, you can unstage and remove them from repository with:

```
git rm --cached -r file/or/directory/path
```

Answer (score 1):

From the gitignore(5) man page:

> The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by git remain untracked.
>
> To ignore uncommitted changes in a file that is already tracked, use `git update-index --assume-unchanged`.
>
> To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.

Answer (score 1):

`git status` shows *.project* folders because they are already tracked.
You need to remove them from your repository: `git rm --cached a/b/.project`

To ignore all the *.java files except those that are on a specific folder, your *.gitignore* should look like this:

```
*.java  
!a/specific/folder/*.java
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, however when I do it rm --cached it removed the files from the changes not staged to the untracked files list. How do I get rid of the untracked files list from showing when I do git status?